# Is there a python library to provide definitions of words that are articles of speech/ conjunctions

Tags: python, wordnet

I am writing a python script that returns definitions of words. I have already implemented wordnet in the NLTK toolkit, but it does not include common articles of speech (who, the, from, and etc.). Is there a library that has this functionality? I have found other python libraries, but they all implement wordnet for their definitions.